# XML reading - Deserialize vs XElement.Load

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xelement

my question is fairly simple, which method should I use and why for parsing XML files?

Right now I have function for that:

```
 return new EdiFile
            {
                SPPLR_MAILBOX = xmlDoc.Element("SPPLR_MAILBOX").Value,
                MESSAGE_ID = xmlDoc.Element("MESSAGE_ID").Value,
                ATTRIBUTE05 = xmlDoc.Element("ATTRIBUTE05").Value,
                Levels0 = (from a in xmlDoc.Element("LEVELS0").Elements("LEVEL0")
                           select new Level0
                           {
                               PLT_NUM = a.Element("PLT_NUM").Value,
                               PLT_LABEL_ID = a.Element("PLT_LABEL_ID").Value,
                               BOX_QTY = a.Element("BOX_QTY").Value,
                               PLT_WEIGHT = a.Element("PLT_WEIGTH").Value,
                               PLT_DIMENSION = a.Element("PLT_DIMENSION").Value,
                               PLT_CHEM = a.Element("PLT_CHEM").Value,
                               PLT_NOT_STACK = a.Element("PLT_NOT_STACK").Value,
                               PLT_NOTE = a.Element("PLT_NOTE").Value,
                               ATTRIBUTE01 = a.Element("ATTRIBUTE01").Value,
                               ATTRIBUTE02 = a.Element("ATTRIBUTE02").Value,
                               ATTRIBUTE03 = a.Element("ATTRIBUTE03").Value,
                               ATTRIBUTE04 = a.Element("ATTRIBUTE04").Value,
                               ATTRIBUTE05 = a.Element("ATTRIBUTE05").Value,
                               Levels1 = (from b in a.Element("LEVELS1").Elements("LEVEL1")
                                          select new Level1
                                          {
                                              BOX_NUM = b.Element("BOX_NUM").Value,
                                              BOX_LABEL_ID = b.Element("BOX_LABEL_ID").Value,
                                              Items = (from c in b.Element("ITEMS").Elements("ITEM")
                                                       select new Item
                                                       {
                                                           SPPLR_ITEM = c.Element("SPPLR_ITEM").Value,
                                                           CUST_ITEM = c.Element("CUST_ITEM").Value,
                                                           ATTRIBUTE01 = c.Element("ATTRIBUTE01").Value,
                                                           ATTRIBUTE02 = c.Element("ATTRIBUTE02").Value,
                                                           ATTRIBUTE03 = c.Element("ATTRIBUTE03").Value,
                                                           ATTRIBUTE04 = c.Element("ATTRIBUTE04").Value,
                                                           ATTRIBUTE05 = c.Element("ATTRIBUTE05").Value,
                                                           Lots = (from d in c.Element("LOTS").Elements("LOT")
                                                                   select new Lot
                                                                   {
                                                                       LOT_NUM = d.Element("LOT_NUM").Value,
                                                                       LOT_LABEL_ID = d.Element("LOT_LABEL_ID").Value,
                                                                       LOT_NOTE = d.Element("LOT_NOTE").Value,
                                                                       LOT_EXP_DATE = d.Element("LOT_EXP_DATE").Value,
                                                                       QTY = d.Element("QTY").Value,
                                                                       UOM = d.Element("UOM").Value,
                                                                       ATTRIBUTE01 = d.Element("ATTRIBUTE01").Value,
                                                                       ATTRIBUTE02 = d.Element("ATTRIBUTE02").Value,
                                                                       ATTRIBUTE03 = d.Element("ATTRIBUTE03").Value,
                                                                       ATTRIBUTE04 = d.Element("ATTRIBUTE04").Value,
                                                                       ATTRIBUTE05 = d.Element("ATTRIBUTE05").Value
                                                                   }).ToList()
                                                       }).ToList()
                                          }).ToList()
                           }).ToList()
            };
```

But should I use deserialize? I learnt about serialization yesterday.

I cant really find any source explaining my method, vs deserialization.

Can someone get me any insight please?

Comment: `XElement.Load` deserializes as well. It generates XElement, XAttribute instances instead of your own classes. Your code does more than just load though, it *transforms* the input into your classes. `Level0` comes from `LEVELS0/LEVEL0`.

Comment: One advantage of you doing the deserialize manually is, that you have full control over the naming convention and you know up front which properties exist in your class. The `XElement.Load` creates an anonymous class and you will need to find out (by Reflection?) where your values are.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, so far for reading I think I will stick with my current way of doing it.

Comment: I always tell people that there are many ways of parsing xml.  The method to use depends on the size of the xml, the amount of data you need to get from the xml, and the structure of the xml.  Most cases xml files have more levels of hierarchy than is needed and using custom parsing like you have done will flatten the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is more performance and flexie, because you have control on processing xml file. Serialization is using reflection and it is less performance.